# Setting up build for VS 2013 solution without VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, portable-class-library, build-tools

I'm trying to setup build VM (Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter) for old solution done in Visual Studio 2013, targeting .NET 4.5. Besides standard .NET projects, it has Silverlight and Portable library project in there too.
Portable libraries are targeting .NET 4.5 and Silverlight 5.

**I'm trying to set it up without having to install Visual Studio 2013.**

I have tried installing .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0, but for both it says it's already installed. Check.

So far, I have installed:

- Microsoft Build Tools 2013
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760 Team
- Explorer 2017 standalone installer
  https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15

My build script is working fine, it goes like this:

```
%msbuild% "%solution_path%" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=%msbuild_configuration%  /p:Platform="Any CPU" /clp:ErrorsOnly;WarningsOnly /fl /flp:logfile=%output_file%;Append;verbosity=normal /verbosity:quiet /nologo /m /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

*Script is working on my machine*<sup>TM</sup>

First error I got was:
(This was reported on portable library project as it is first to build)

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.0\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I tried fixing this with `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` but it didn't help (I left the flag in command line anyway for future).

I tried to fool msbuild by placing needed files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable`.

Now I'm getting different error for same portable library project:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataMemberAttribute' could
>   not be found (areyou missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

This is not the only error. It's reporting error for each CLR type it finds.

Portable library in csproj has:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

How to make this build work? What am I missing?

Comment: I think I'm just missing .NET SDK. I'm downloading it now...

Comment: Developer Pack 4.5.2 from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks didn't help.